# Update table column based on two other table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, inner-join

I need to update a column in one of my tables based on data from 2 other tables.

So I want the column isAvailable, in the table questionObjectives, to be set to 1 based on 2 conditions and this is what I have:

```
UPDATE
    dbo.questObjectives
SET
    isAvailable = 1
FROM
    dbo.questObjectives qo
INNER JOIN
    dbo.dungeonList dl
ON 
    qo.questID = dl.questID
    WHERE dl.dungeonType = 17
    AND qo.objectiveID IN(SELECT objectiveID FROM gameMissions)
```

So to translate, isAvailable should be set to 1 if:

```
the linked dungeonList type is 17
the questionObjectives objectiveID is in the table gameMissions
```

So I thought I had my logic right, but I keep getting this error:

```
'invalid column name isAvailable.'
```

But it is there.  It is in the questionObjectives table so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: When you alias your update table, you `UPDATE Alias ...` i.e. `update qo`

Comment: The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object) are very good at answering syntax type questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update qo
set qo.isavailable = 1
from questObjectives qo
inner join dungeonList dl on qo.questID = dl.questID
where 
    dl.dungeonList = 17
    and exists (select 1 from gameMissions gm where gm.objectiveID  = qo.objectiveID)
```

The main problem with your query is that you have target table `questObjectives` both in the `update` and `from` clauses; you should have it just once, in the `from` clause, and then refer to the alias in the `update` clause.

I also rewrote the `in` condition as a correlated subquery with `exists` - the logic is the same, but this might perform better.